# Accessing a database using visual c++ and OLEDB

Tags: c++, visual-c++, oledb

Does anybody have an example of working with database using Visual C++ and OLEDB? What should I include on top of my code? 
I have searched the internet and most examples are using C# or VB. Examples written by C++ are usually not complete.

I really appreciate your help.

Best,
Shadi.

Comment: Examples using VB (not .Net) should be pretty straight-forward to translate to C++. Do you have any specific problems with that?

Comment: try this out http://sqlines.com/migration/embedded-sql-api/cpp/sql-server-esql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use ADO to do this.  Writing code directly to OLE DB from C/C++ is a fair  bit of work (understatement). If you google for `c++ ado`, there are a number of hits.  The top two are [this one on codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/ado/article.php/c6729__1/) and [one on codersource](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-database/c-ado-select-sample.aspx). They both look like good examples.