# What is the ConnectionString to create a OdbcConnection for an access mdb file in x64?

Tags: c++, ms-access, odbc, 64-bit, connection-string

Extending on this question [What is the ConnectionString to create a OdbcConnection for an access mdb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567220/what-is-the-connectionstring-to-create-a-odbcconnection-for-an-access-mdb-file) , I'ld like to know how to write the connectionstring to connect to an .mdb file from a 64bit application - except this time I'm trying to do it from a c++ 64bit application instead of C#. Not sure if that makes a difference so I put it here :)

When I compile for 32bit, I can connect to my mdb file with

```
"driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=mlog.mdb;UID=;PWD="
```

I'm not sure if this is the optimal way, but it works.

Now I need to compile my application in 64bit. the connectionstring from above doesn't work anymore, so I checked out http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ and tried

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=mlog.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

but no success.

I use

```
ret = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, 0, connectionstring, SQL_NTS, outstr, 1024, &outstrlen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) ...
```

to try to connect. But it always fails. when I call SQLGetDiagRec(), it returns empty strings.

I also installed the Access 2010 64bit drivers. Checking c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe tehre is a "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" installed, version 14.00.7010.1000 in ACEODBC.DLL .

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed on your machine?

Comment: I thought that this question will arise, so I added a note about that at the end of the Question by editing it.

Comment: I haven't worked with Visual C++, but in C# the `Sql...` database objects are specific to SQL Server and will not work with OLEDB drivers for Access (and other databases). Instead, the `OleDb...` objects must be used. Is there an `OleDbDriverConnect` equivalent to the `SQLDriverConnect` object that you are currently trying to use?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Maybe you are right. But I don't know yet. I'm always confused with what's JET, ODBC, OLDDB, ADODB. There is this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx that roughly sums it up, except for JET. So should I use/try OLEDB or ADODB?

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2653046/2144390) suggests that ADO is easier to use than OLEDB from C/C++ applications.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking for the solution, OdbcConnection 64 bits can connect to Access databases with this connection string :

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=X:\fullpath\database.mdb;
```

Or, if you need login :

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=X:\fullpath\database.accdb;Uid=MyLogin;Pwd=MyPassword;
```

Of course, you need to install the 64 bits access database driver.

You can find it here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920